# Apache mod_userdir and php permissions

Tags: php, apache-2.4, permissions, mod-userdir

I have a setup with many users, who can host their personal webpage (served by apache via `mod_userdir`), located under `public_html` in their homes. php support is also enabled in apache.

At the moment I have the following configuration in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir <home basedir>/*/public_html
        UserDir disabled root

        <Directory <home basedir>/*/public_html>
                AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes Options
                Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
                <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                        Require all granted
                </Limit>
                <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                        Require all denied
                </LimitExcept>
        </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that, since every php script is run by user `www-data`, each user page has permissions over every other users' `public_html`. For example, I can get a php reverse shell and inspect other users' content.

I have tried to add

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "."
```

inside the `Directory` tag above. This prevents the security hole described above, but actually only allows the php script to go down the directory hierarchy. For example

```
<?php
chdir('assets');
echo getcwd();
chdir('..');
echo "<br>";
echo getcwd();
?>
```

produces

```
<home>/public_html/assets
<home>/public_html/assets
```

The problem is solved if the `<home>/public_html` path is hardcoded in the `open_basedir` variable, but of course I need to be able to do this for all users via some variable.
Does apache store the wildcard (`<home basedir>/*/public_html`) match in some variable that I can access inside the `Directory` tag? Or are any other better ways to do this, for instance running each user page in a chroot-like environment?

Comment: Did you have a look at [mod_suphp](https://github.com/lightsey/mod_suphp)?